# Making an Ajax request to a page method in ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to call a page method belonging to a MVC Controller from another site, by means of:

```
$.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "http://localhost:54953/Home/ola",
          data: "",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data) {
                console.log(data.Name);
          }
        });
```

the method code is as follows, really simple, just to test:

```
 public ActionResult ola()
    {

        return Json(new ActionInfo()
        {
            Name = "ola"
        },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

I've seen this aproach being suggested here, and I actually like it a lot, should it work...

When I run this, firebug gets a 200 OK, but the data received is null.

I've tried a lot of different approaches, like having the data in text (wish grants me "(an empty string)" instead of just "null") or returning string in the server method...

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance,

João

Comment: What is the access modifier on your ActionInfo.Name member? If it's non-public, it won't be serialized into the JSON result.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the JQuery? Put the statement "debugger;" in your success method then you can inspect the data.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried returning your JSON like so...

```
public ActionResult ola()
{
    return Json(new { Name = "ola" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Ola()
{
    // No need to use a custom ActionInfo type here, an anonymous type
    // will be just fine:
    return Json(new { Name = "ola" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

View:

```
$(function {
    $.getJSON('/home/ola', function(json) {
        alert(json.Name);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try returning `JsonResult` from the controller action method. Method signature would then be `public JsonResult ola()`. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the feedback. I found out that everything I was doing was right and wrong at the same time.

the requests were all functional, but the request was being made to a different domain, wich is automatically blocked by the browsers (except IE). It's a question of security. 
But since the request was meant to work on a mobile device, when i tested it there, it worked perfectly.

Once again, thanks to everyone who answered, i'll adopt some of the ideas shown here :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are making an ajax call cross domain. Have you tried setting your data type to

```
dataType: jsonp
```

[jquery ajax cross domain](http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2010/07/cross-domain-jsonp-using-asp-net-mvc-and-jquery/)